# What is lost and gained by going prestige?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

What exactly is gained/lost from going prestige in Black Ops? I've heard that you keep the different layers, but not the various camo and attachments.

Comment: You may want to see my answer for the complete list of thigns you do not lose.

Comment: im not sure what the point is besides gaining these small rewards. the golden gun is cool but not worth all the effort or aggravation unless you're just that good. I'm just going to 4 and I have almost all the perks on pro from prestiging previously. a new COD comes out in November. I really don't feel like going through all the pro challenges again. I'd rather just keep my stuff and get better for the next game.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rewards for prestige are as follows:

- Prestige 1    Prestige Leaderboard, Custom Class 6
- Prestige 3    Custom Class 7
- Prestige 5    Custom Class 8
- Prestige 7    Custom Class 9
- Prestige 9    Custom Class 10
- Prestige 11   Face Tattoos
- Prestige 13   Clan Tag Colors
- Prestige 14   Golden Camo
- Prestige 15   Prestige Playlists

Apparently you lose everything except for emblems.

Comment: even purely visual things lile face paint, gun camos, etc? Upsetting...

Comment: I think golden camo is in 1'st presigue lvl 14?

Comment: I don't get it, what's the point of loosing EVERYTHING you bought up to prestige? Is there a reason to do it other than extra custom classes, a leaderboard, and some eyecandy?

Comment: Well, there's also the satisfaction of starting from scratch.  Plus, those extra classes come in handy when you're like me and have 6 classes which all differ from a 7th by one perk or attachment.  On MW2, I have a silenced smg class with each of throwing knife, semtex, and claymore, for different moods and different opponents, plus three AR classes, plus a cold blooded version of 2 smg classes and an AR class.  That's 9 classes already... :D

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that you don't lose absolutely everything when prestiging.

Some of the things I've noted you don't lose:

- Layers, shapes, and the "banner" for your playercard/emblem
- If you bought the emblem or clan tag option for guns, this is not lost when you repurchase the gun(as in, you don't have to rebuy the emblem/clan tag for the gun)
- Camo for guns is not lost, so you don't have to rebuy them. (But you do have to wait til the appropriate level to equip them)
- (unconfirmed) face paint is not lost, so you don't have to rebuy it.

The important thing to me that IS lost is pro perks. You have to start from scratch and complete the challenges all over again(along with actually buying the pro perk). I consider this a design flaw, but it's the way it works.